# How to call a MySQL stored procedure in Bitrix24 application

Tags: php, mysql, bitrix

I need to call MySQL stored procedures in Bitrix24 application and use it for the query result. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Install php extension https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

Implement the following architecture:

```
class MssqlSqlHelper extends Bitrix\Main\DB\SqlHelper
{
    public function quote($identifier)
    {
        if (self::isKnowFunctionalCall($identifier))
        {
            return $identifier
        }
        else
        {
            return parent::quote($identifier);
        }
    }
}
```

Where self::isKnownFunctionCall is a verification method that returns true if foo_table_procedure() is in $identifier.

```
public static function getTableName()
{
         return "foo_table_procedure()";
}
```